# Test if functions were called with arguments

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

So... I've just wanted to check if my *sut* uses a dependency in such a way, that it gets called at least N times with proper arguments. I failed to find a way to do so without dirty hacks of looking up `.mock.calls` entries and finding proper one. Ideally, I'd like to have code that looks like that:

```
it('...', () => {
  const dependency = jest.fn();
  const sut = createSut(dependency);

  sut();

  // that is of course wrong because of syntax but it shows what I want:
  expect(dependency).toBeCalledWith({ some: 'arguments' }).times(5);

  // this doesn't work - if at least one call was made it will always pass
  for (let i = 0; i < 5: ++i)
    expect(dependency).toBeCalledWith({ some: 'arguments' });

  // this doesn't work either, 'cause at least one proper call will make tests pass
  expect(dependency.mock.calls.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(5);
  expect(dependency).toBeCalledWith({ some: 'arguments' });
});
```

Is there an option to get what I want in `jest` without using other libraries, like `chai`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write your tests by using [jests's matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect).

```
// Called just 5 times
expect(dependency).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(5);

// Called with same argument
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(time => {
  expect(dependency).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(time, {
    some: 'arguments',
  });
});

// Called with different arguments
const expectedArguments = [
  {some: 'arguments'},
  null,
  14,
  {some:'arguments'},
  {some:'arguments'},
];

expectedArguments.forEach((argument, index) => {
  const callNumber = index + 1;
  expect(dependency).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(callNumber, argument);
});
```

Comment: No I cannot. I don't want to bind to actual order of calls. What if the calls to `dependency` happen with following params: {some: 'arguments'}, null, 14, then 4 time {some:'arguments'} -  I still want this behaviour to pass tests.

Comment: Once you have a list of expected arguments, Jest will follow. See updated examples.

Comment: I think you didn't understand. I don't want to know with what other arguments my dependency might get called nor in which order, to not lock myself up for future refactorings of SUT. Therefore the only option I see is to filter through `.mock.calls` collection. I just wanted to know if there's a better option for that.